Validating ACF fields and loading existing values on Woocommerce checkout
I am using ACF with Woocommerce to add custom fields to the checkout page. My code is below and is based on answers to this question:
Display checkout ACF Advanced Custom Fields and save the value in WooCommerce
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'checkout_display_acf_field' ); 
function checkout_display_acf_field() { 
    $acf_field_key_arr = array ( // Here set the all required fields Keys in the array
        'field_663d53424eeb3',
        'field_663d5100cb98f',
        'field_663d5144be5b5',
        'field_663d516a53a0f'
    );
    
    // Loop through each field key in the array
    foreach ( $acf_field_key_arr as $acf_field_key ) {
        acf_form( array(
            'form' => false, 
            'fields' => array( $acf_field_key )
        ) );
    }
}

This works for displaying the fields, but even though they are marked required in ACF (and they show up on the checkout page with an asterisk), they don't actually get validated. The customer can just proceed to the next part of the checkout without having to enter values.
My checkout page is created using a plugin called FunnelKit. I don't know if this has anything to do with the validation issue.
Secondly, logged-in users may have already answered the questions in the four ACF fields (during registration or a previous order). If so, I would like to load the existing values so the customer doesn't have to fill them out again (or can change the values).
I have tried these scripts for validation:
//* Validate custom checkout fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'checkout_field_validation', 20, 2 );
function checkout_field_validation( $data, $errors ){

            if ( empty( $_POST['field_663d53424eeb3'] ) )
                $errors->add( 'field_663d53424eeb3',  __( "Please fill in the participant $j full name" ), 'error' );

            if ( empty( $_POST['field_663d5100cb98f'] ) )
                $errors->add( 'field_663d5100cb98f',  __( "Please fill in the participant $j email address" ), 'error' );
        }

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process' );

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( ! $_POST['field_663d53424eeb3'] ) {
        wc_add_notice( esc_html__( 'Please enter something into this new shiny field.' ), 'error' );
    }
}

add_filter('acf/validate_value/key=field_663d53424eeb3', 'validate_email_field', 20, 4);
function validate_email_field( $valid, $value, $field, $input ) {
  if (!$valid) {
    return $valid;
  }
  if( email_exists( $value ) ) {
    $valid = 'email exists';
  }
   return $valid;
}

For the loading of field values, I have tried:
add_action('acf/prepare_field/key=field_663d53424eeb3', 'populate_how_did_you_hear');

function populate_how_did_you_hear($field) {
  $field['value'] = get_field('field_663d53424eeb3', 'user_'.$user->ID);
  return $field;
}

add_filter('acf/load_field/key=field_663d53424eeb3', 'set_default_user', 20, 1);
function set_default_user($field) {
  $field['default_value'] = get_field('field_663d53424eeb3', 'user_'.$user->ID);
  return $field;
}


Note that ACF Fields doesn't work with newly High-Performance Order Storage (HPOS), so check if HPOS is enabled, by going in WooCommerce settings > advanced > features...

HPOS is not on because I use a couple of incompatible plugins, but thanks for letting me know that's something else I should check.
